# how to loop through a list of strings and print in Tabula form

Tags: python, django, list

am practicing python I have this issue here, I have a list of three teams,`teams = ['manu','spurs','roma']` just looping through the index 0 i was able to print the outcome

```html
teams = ['manu','spurs','roma']
for m in teams[0]:
    print(m,'\t')
```

` but can I print all the teams in a tabula form like
[image: see image]

help out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data)

Comment: it does not its kind  different

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do it something like this. Print letter by letter in for loops with try/except block. Use `print(end='\n')` to create new line after printed all letters from index 'x'. (You can write `print()` without `end='\n'` but it will be less understandable.

```
teams = ['manu','spurs','roma']
for x in range(len(max(teams, key=len))):
    for m in teams:
        try:
            print(m[x], end='\t')
        except IndexError:
            print("", end='\t')
    print(end='\n')
```

Comment: This prints everything in one line. Add print('\n') at the end of the loop

Comment: this works but i just don't understand the  print() at the end any explanation

Comment: I added `print()` to create a new line after the printed letter 'x' form all words. I will try to modify it to create more efficient code and edit post after that.

Answer (score 0):

Is your data fixed? Cause if not maybe you already know on how to get those data you have and put it in the loop. Anyways this might help you.

```
teams = ['manu','spurs','roma']
for m,s,r in zip(teams[0],teams[1],teams[2]):
    print(m,s,r,'\t')
```

--**UPDATE**---

I always felt I've seen this before... so luckily I've found it and you can have it this way if you want. Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622169/vertical-print-string-python3-2)

```
from itertools import zip_longest

teams = ['manu','spurs','roma']
text=' '.join(teams)

for x in zip_longest(*text.split(), fillvalue=' '):
    print ('\t'.join(x))
```

Comment: It doesn't print the ending s from spurs

Comment: sure the s inst there

Comment: *Updates , Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The repsponse of K.Oleksy is great but uses the exceptions to catch the end of the string. I'll juste show you how to avoid that as Exceptions are not made for that.

```
teams = ['nusqdgqsdgsq','spjurs','romaaa']

max_lenght = len(max(teams, key = len))
print(max_lenght)
for i in range(max_lenght):
    for team_index in range(len(teams)):
        if (i < len(teams[team_index])):
            print(teams[team_index][i], end = '\t')
        else:
            print('  ', end = '')
    print()
```